# WP7 Localisation and resource files

Tags: windows-phone-7, resources, localization

I have seen several examples detailing how to localise a WP7 app.

I have got a resource file for the Spanish language working fine  - its named
 AppResource.es-ES.resx.

Within the emulator this seems to work when I select the language as Spanish and any of the Spanish speaking countries i.e   Spanish (Mexico, Spanish (Chile)

It has been suggested via another source that the ".es-ES" part of the file means that it will only work for Spain itself, and that to make it effective across all Spanish speaking countries it would need to be named  AppResource.es.resx. 
I have not found any documentation to support this.

Safe to assume that a file named AppResource.es-ES.resx will be effective in all Spanish speaking countries?

Answer (score 2):

> I have not found any documentation to support this.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052(v=vs.85).aspx

> Safe to assume that a file named AppResource.es-ES.resx will be effective in all Spanish speaking countries?

No. As you been told, rename it `AppResource.es.resx` will make it active for all the 9 Spanish countries listed on the list above.

Comment: Okay - sounds good.  And what should go into the csproj in the SupportedCultures section?

Comment: Thank you.  Looking at localising the application title and, as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967550%28v=VS.92%29.aspx there are quite specific strings for each culture..  Nothing generic as per the AppResources file in the application?  And in this list nothing for Spanish speaking countries like Chile?

Comment: The tile localization is only for the marketplace supported languages. Users in Chile will use the international marketplace, for which the language code is `en`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [National Language Support (NLS) API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx) `es-ES` means `Spanish - Spain` so you cant't assume that it will be effective in all Spanish speaking countries. Use `es` instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not safe to assume sobecause in Silverlight CultureInfo Class is there to facilitate the localization which says that,

> "The CultureInfo class specifies a unique name for each culture, based
>   on RFC 4646. The name is a combination of an ISO 639 two-letter
>   lowercase culture code associated with a language and an ISO 3166
>   two-letter uppercase subculture code associated with a country or
>   region".

[For more information you can access this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)